# How to handle request for email address

Tags: discussion

Sometimes it happens that you answer a particular question (or set of related questions) that ends up creating in the OP the impression that you have become their personal tutor, and they ask for your email address.

A few approaches one can use: ignore, be rude, be polite, give in.

I lean towards "be polite but say no".

Is there a site policy I could point to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This Mother Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138788/can-i-give-my-email-id-in-reply-to-user-comment) says,

> You *can* give it if you are so inclined, but by no means you *have* to.
>
> It's highly unorthodox to ask for someone's E-Mail address, and often it's to bug you for free one-on-one support. Which you are absolutely not obliged to give.

So it's basically your choice to do that, there isn't a rule forbidding or forcing it.

If you do not want to give out your email, then I would err on the side of caution and politely respond with something like, *I would rather not give out my personal email address, but if you do have further questions, go ahead and post it here, where I, and others, will be able to see it and answer you.*

I would like to point out that some of us do include our email addresses in the `About Me` section of the profile page. I have included mine there since I signed up almost 2 years ago and I think it's been used by a grand total of 4 users (on 8-10 emails, none of which were actually homework related, just side discussions).

Comment: Thanks - that mother meta is exactly the link I can use to politely say "no".

Comment: Note that the line in the profile page with e-mail address is *private*, no one can see that. You have put your address also in your profile text though, which everyone *can* see.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Hmm, I had forgotten that (I can see mine!), I'll update the answer to point that out.

Comment: Yes - I can see my own email address in my profile...

Comment: Mods can also see yours ;)

Comment: @Floris honestly, you don't _need_ a justification not to give out your email address. But the post is there for you to point to if you want to.

Comment: No need to even be polite. Just say no. Policy doesn't say you have to be polite, just not a jerk. ;P